# Ao clicar em qualquer lugar da página abrir uma nova pagina e com limite por tempo?

Tags: javascript

Como faço para quando o usuário clicar em qualquer lugar do meu website abrir um site externo determinado em uma nova guia e com cookies para limitar a abertura do site determinado por tempo?

Comment: `target='_blank'` - já testaste isso?

Comment: Denis o Guilherme adicionou _"qualquer lugar da página"_ na descrição da pergunta. É isso que queres? ou é em links `<a>` que tens na página?

Comment: @Sergio eu não adicionei a descrição da pergunta, eu copiei o conteudo da pergunta e coloquei no título, são as palavras do próprio AP =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, verdade. Mas ainda não percebi se ele tem âncoras ou se quer fazer tudo com JavaScript.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento achei que a resposta aqui é mais completa. Denis, é boa ideia esclarecer perguntas nos comentários. Para bem da pergunta, da tua aprendizagem e também do tipo de comunicação que queres ter com a comunidade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em resumo seria isto:

```
<script>
(function () {
    var isOpened = false;

    //Troque aqui pelo site desejado
    var siteUrl  = "http://www.google.com.br";

    document.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (!isOpened) {
            isOpened = !!window.open(siteUrl, "_blank");
        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

Adiciona o evento click ao `document.`, use `window.open` sem parametros de configuração de janela, criei uma variavel `isOpened` pra verificar se o pop-up já foi aberto, acaso tenha sido clicado então ignora os próximos cliques (também dá pra usar `document.removeEventListener`)

> **Nota <sup>[1]</sup>:** Eu adicionei o `!!` na frente do `window.open` porque alguns plugins de bloqueio de popup bloqueiam até chamadas vindas de cliques, então `window.open` retorna `null`, assim você saberá se o popup foi aberto ou não.
>
> **Nota <sup>[2]</sup>:**  Usei uma função anonima pra isolar as variaveis do escopo global, assim evitando acidentes.

### Limitar pop-up por tempo <sup>[extra]</sup>

O AP me solicitou uma funcionalidade extra, estou separado do contexto acima pois o código acima acredito que ajudará pessoas em especificas situações, neste caso o AP deseja limitar a cada 24 horas um click, ou seja abriu o pop-up uma vez só daqui 24 horas irá ocorrer novamente, mesmo que atualize a página.

Isto pode ser resolvido usando cookies, por exemplo:

```
<script>
//Função pra verificar se a janela foi já aberta hoje
function checkOpenPopupToday()
{
      return /(^|;\s)isopenedpopup=1(;|$)/.test(document.cookie);
}

//Função pra definir em horas que a janela foi aberta
function setOpenPopupToday(hours)
{
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = "isopenedpopup=1; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
}

(function () {
    //Troque aqui pelo site desejado
    var siteUrl  = "http://www.google.com.br";

    //Troque aqui pelo tempo em horas desejado para impedir que o popup abra neste intervalo
    var hours = 24;

    document.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        //Verificar pelo cookie
        if (!checkOpenPopupToday())
        {
            //Verificar se o popup abriu com o clique
            if (!!window.open(siteUrl, "_blank"))
            {
                  //Se a janela foi aberta define o tempo para bloquear novas aberturas
                  setOpenPopupToday(hours);
            }
        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo!

Comment: Mais uma coisa se quiser limitar 1 click a cada 24 horas como seria?

Comment: @denis Pode-se utilizar uma lógica usando cookies.

Comment: @denis editei a resposta com um exemplo usando cookies

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ok obrigado vou editar a pergunta